# How to create a user first-time screen guide for my application

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I need to create a short first-time here user guide for an application I am building and i don't know what to search for.

What I need is a dialogs guide, like Facebook does when you create a new page. For those that don't know, when you create a new fb page, Facebook guides you with small dialogs for key actions on the page like share,post etc..

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a feature tour library. Search for that term and you're likely to find what you're looking for. [Joyride](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) is a popular one. [Crumble](http://tommoor.github.com/crumble/) is another option, but I don't think it's quite as customizable. Both of these are jQuery plugins.

Comment: Do you know of any library like this for iOS? Tried searching the term but nothing came up

Comment: This was exactly what i had in mind!!! Thanks Justin!

Comment: Was also looking for something like this. This one looks really nice! (http://xbsoftware.com/products/enjoyhint/)

Answer (score 9):

Here is the list of jquery plugins I know for website tour 1. http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/ 2. http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aSimpleTour/ 3. http://clu3.github.io/bootstro.js/# 4.http://tracelytics.github.io/pageguide/ 5.http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/ 6. http://ryanfunduk.com/jquery-tourbus/ 7. http://eragonj.github.io/Trip.js/

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would just want to check if some cookie exists.

If the cookie doesn't exist, then show the guide and set the cookie. If the cookie does exist, then do nothing (keep the guides hidden).